# MySql Query - Joining

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
articles
id int auto_increment
title VARCHAR
desc VARCHAR
etc

tags
id int auto_increment
articleId int
tag Varchar
```

The idea is that articles have multiple tags.

I want to select an article with all of it's tags in a single field separated by a comma or something.

The result would look like:

```
title    |   desc    |      tags       |
---------------------------------------
article1 |   desc1   | Tech,Science    |
article2 |   desc2   | Drama,Tv,Funny  |
```

I'm looking for help with the query to do this.

Here's what I have... I know it's not right... I'm guessing I need some kind of join and concatenation?

```
SELECT * 
FROM portfolio.articles, portfolio.tags 
WHERE articles.id = tags.articleId;
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the group_concat function

so you would have something like this:

```
select
a.title,
a.desc,
group_concat(t.tag) 

from articles a
inner join tags t on a.id = t.articleId

group by 
a.title, a.desc
```

this will seperate each tag with a comma

Comment: when I started typing there were no answers. Both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT a.title, a.desc, group_concat(t.tag) as tags
  FROM portfolio.articles a
  join portfolio.tags t
    on a.id = t.articleId
 group by a.title, a.desc
```

You want to use the group_concat function, which is basically vertical concatenation.

Comment: +1 for being first . . . and not by a subtle amount.  4.5 minutes seems like a long time to type an answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks... site can be bizarre sometimes

Comment: When you hover over the time, you can see the exact time stamp.  I learned this from Aaron Bertrand, once upon a time.  He was first, but at least in that case the difference would have been in seconds, not minutes.

Comment: Ah, I'll have to remember that. It should probably just show it underneath the 'x hrs/mins ago' indicator, and/or order the posts in ascending order of time beneath the question.